# Use wireshark in Ubuntu 22.04,the virtual machine will crash after running the packet capture analysis

Tags: linux, client-server, wireshark

every time i test my server and client,and i start the wireshark in Ubuntu22.04,and then the virtual machine will crash and begin to show mant things,some of them is like:
audit:type=1400 audit(1687714688.484:264): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" class="file" profile="snap.snapd-desktop-integration" name="/etc/hosts/" pid=23994 comm="snap-desktop-1" requested_mask='r' denied_mask="r".
I really hope to know how to fix this because it really influence the use of virtual machine,and each time it occurs i need to restart my virtual machine.

Comment: It looks like apparmor on the virtual machine is restricting what you are doing. Did you install this virtual machine yourself? If you are clear about the security implication, you could disable apparmor, which is the easiest approach.

Comment: I did this and it just becomes all black in virtual machine when i start the wireshark

Comment: I am sorry that my suggestion did not help. May I ask how did you disable apparmor? Was it through `systemd`?

Comment: Yes!I disable apparmor with systemd and the code is like :
`sudo systemctl stop apparmor`
`sudo systemctl disable apparmor`
I finally choose to restart a virtual machineI think something is wrong with some underlying part of my virtual machine，and it is tough to solve,so i restart a virtual machine,it now looks good.